# Dúvida com RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc

É possível fazer um redirect quando o site usa uma ancora? 
Eu tenho está situação, onde a minha ancora tem o nome de contato, queria redirecionar para está parte do código.

```html
 public ActionResult email()
{
   return RedirectToAction("index#contato", "Home");

}
```